# Compression in MongoDb 3.2 does not work

Tags: mongodb

I installed MongoDb 3.2, and configured snappy compression in mongodb configuration file:

engine: wiredTiger
   wiredTiger:
       engineConfig:
           cacheSizeGB: 99
           journalCompressor: none
       collectionConfig:
           blockCompressor: snappy
       indexConfig:
           prefixCompression: true

However I do not think compression actually work as I could see average object size in the collection is about the same (I filled collection created from scratch by the same objects right after configuration change and service restart):

```
MMAPv1 no-compression avgObjSize: 5kb
WiredTiger snappy avgObjSize: 4kb
WiredTiger zlib avgObjSize: 4kb
```

when I run stats on collection here is what I see for "snappy":

```
"compression" : {
        "compressed pages read" : NumberInt(0), 
        "compressed pages written" : NumberInt(5), 
        "page written failed to compress" : NumberInt(0), 
        "page written was too small to compress" : NumberInt(4), 
        "raw compression call failed, additional data available" : NumberInt(0), 
        "raw compression call failed, no additional data available" : NumberInt(0), 
        "raw compression call succeeded" : NumberInt(0)
    },
```

for zlib:

```
{
    "compressed pages read" : NumberInt(0), 
    "compressed pages written" : NumberInt(1), 
    "page written failed to compress" : NumberInt(0), 
    "page written was too small to compress" : NumberInt(3), 
    "raw compression call failed, additional data available" : NumberInt(0), 
    "raw compression call failed, no additional data available" : NumberInt(1), 
    "raw compression call succeeded" : NumberInt(2)
}
```

Not sure how to read this info, and not sure how can I detect what's wrong with compression.

I should also say I had only few (like 10) objects in each scenario. Would it be enough to accurately measure average object compression ratio?

**UPDATE:** with 1188 documents mongodb ver3 shown around 50% better compression ratio comparing to mongodb ver2.6 (MMAPv1), however got no difference between snappy and zlib: dataSize and avgObjSize are the same for some reason. When I request statistics it shown WiredTiger:creationString:...block_compressor=zlib.. for the first database and block_compressor=snappy for the second one, so databases and collections seemed to be created with right compression algorithms

Comment: What kind of data are yo adding to your collection

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that it contains regular bson text, not binary data.  .net driver parses .net objects into bson 5kb objects (unpacked size)

Comment: insert a few thousand documents and then compare - I suspect you don't have enough data to show any meaningful effects

Comment: That's true as @AdamC has mentioned, have a larger data and Compare

Comment: @AdamC, I used 1188 examples and got some encouraging results on compression for snappy over no-compression, though would still expect better compression ratio. The strange thing zlib did not show any improvements over snappy. Please see updated question for more information. Thanks

Comment: So, quite a while back I tested this (with 3.0) and my results are here: https://comerford.net/2015/02/04/mongodb-3-0-testing-compression/ - I saw significant gains with zlib versus snappy but I was doing it with a large data set. I suspect you won't see real differences between them until you give zlib enough to work with, or perhaps your data is not very compressible. Either way, the only way to really find out is to increase your sample size and check out the results

Comment: Note that collection `dataSize` and `avgObjSize` metrics are unaffected by data compression: these are measures of the MongoDB documents. For the effects of compression, compare the  `storageSize` metric and the ratio of `dataSize` to `storageSize`.

Answer (score 0):

--version 3.4.10 Enterprise

compression will not change the avgObjSize. It will just improve the compression ratio saving disk space; I tested it for a collection (documents: 11553423 and avgObjSize= 6182) worth 21GB  with snappy, when same created with zlib, size of collection reduced to 12GB (avgObjSize= 6182).